# Cannot unhide "All Day Event" on Calendar List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, hidden

At one point I hide the `All Day Event` field on our SP Calendar List since we didn't need it and now we do. Unfortunately, when I went back through the same menu (`List Settings` -> `Content Types` -> `Event` -> `Column Name`) that I usually use to hide/unhide Columns, but the Column Name was unclickable.

[image]

It used to be that `All Day Event` was a link, but now it's not. Any ideas on how I can add this feature back to the forms?

Comment: Did you try Site Settings -> Content Types -> Event -> Column Name?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Unfortunately, even there it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer to my question. In SharePoint Designer, you can check the Event Content Type and nothing happens when you click "Hidden"...unless you click it a lot of times really fast. Then it will let you edit the visibility.

Great job MS. Just great.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this point for so long. Even clicking on 'Hidden' so many times did not work for me.

However, what worked for me in SharePoint Designer was to select the column name and then click on 'Administration Web page' and then change from hidden to optional.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/117250)